# mysql 5.5.41 replication error ubuntu 14.04

Tags: mysql, replication

ip assigned, I can ssh between both machines, scp files from the host to either guest but using mysqlaccess I cannot log into the master instance from the slave instance or using

```
mysqlreplicate --master=replicate@myserver1:3306 --slave=replicate@myserver2:3306 --rpl-user=rpl:rpl

error = cannot connect to master, access denied for 'replicate'@'myserver2' (using password: no)
```

both master and slave instance have `/etc/hosts` setup so the master ip address `192.168.56.101`  myserver1 and slave `102.168.56.102` myserver2

output of the master setup

```
    Variable_name   Value
    Aborted_clients 213
    Aborted_connects    1
    Binlog_cache_disk_use   0
    Binlog_cache_use    0
    Binlog_stmt_cache_disk_use  0
    Binlog_stmt_cache_use   0
    Bytes_received  143
    Bytes_sent  189
    Com_admin_commands  0
    Com_assign_to_keycache  0
    Com_alter_db    0
    Com_alter_db_upgrade    0
    Com_alter_event 0
    Com_alter_function  0
    Com_alter_procedure 0
    Com_alter_server    0
    Com_alter_table 0
    Com_alter_tablespace    0
    Com_analyze 0
    Com_begin   0
    Com_binlog  0
    Com_call_procedure  0
    Com_change_db   0
    Com_change_master   0
    Com_check   0
    Com_checksum    0
    Com_commit  0
    Com_create_db   0
    Com_create_event    0
    Com_create_function 0
    Com_create_index    0
    Com_create_procedure    0
    Com_create_server   0
    Com_create_table    0
    Com_create_trigger  0
    Com_create_udf  0
    Com_create_user 0
    Com_create_view 0
    Com_dealloc_sql 0
    Com_delete  0
    Com_delete_multi    0
    Com_do  0
    Com_drop_db 0
    Com_drop_event  0
    Com_drop_function   0
    Com_drop_index  0
    Com_drop_procedure  0
    Com_drop_server 0
    Com_drop_table  0
    Com_drop_trigger    0
    Com_drop_user   0
    Com_drop_view   0
    Com_empty_query 0
    Com_execute_sql 0
    Com_flush   0
    Com_grant   0
    Com_ha_close    0
    Com_ha_open 0
    Com_ha_read 0
    Com_help    0
    Com_insert  0
    Com_insert_select   0
    Com_install_plugin  0
    Com_kill    0
    Com_load    0
    Com_lock_tables 0
    Com_optimize    0
    Com_preload_keys    0
    Com_prepare_sql 0
    Com_purge   0
    Com_purge_before_date   0
    Com_release_savepoint   0
    Com_rename_table    0
    Com_rename_user 0
    Com_repair  0
    Com_replace 0
    Com_replace_select  0
    Com_reset   0
    Com_resignal    0
    Com_revoke  0
    Com_revoke_all  0
    Com_rollback    0
    Com_rollback_to_savepoint   0
    Com_savepoint   0
    Com_select  1
    Com_set_option  0
    Com_signal  0
    Com_show_authors    0
    Com_show_binlog_events  0
    Com_show_binlogs    0
    Com_show_charsets   0
    Com_show_collations 0
    Com_show_contributors   0
    Com_show_create_db  0
    Com_show_create_event   0
    Com_show_create_func    0
    Com_show_create_proc    0
    Com_show_create_table   0
    Com_show_create_trigger 0
    Com_show_databases  0
    Com_show_engine_logs    0
    Com_show_engine_mutex   0
    Com_show_engine_status  0
    Com_show_events 0
    Com_show_errors 0
    Com_show_fields 0
    Com_show_function_status    0
    Com_show_grants 0
    Com_show_keys   0
    Com_show_master_status  0
    Com_show_open_tables    0
    Com_show_plugins    0
    Com_show_privileges 0
    Com_show_procedure_status   0
    Com_show_processlist    0
    Com_show_profile    0
    Com_show_profiles   0
    Com_show_relaylog_events    0
    Com_show_slave_hosts    0
    Com_show_slave_status   0
    Com_show_status 1
    Com_show_storage_engines    0
    Com_show_table_status   0
    Com_show_tables 0
    Com_show_triggers   0
    Com_show_variables  0
    Com_show_warnings   0
    Com_slave_start 0
    Com_slave_stop  0
    Com_stmt_close  0
    Com_stmt_execute    0
    Com_stmt_fetch  0
    Com_stmt_prepare    0
    Com_stmt_reprepare  0
    Com_stmt_reset  0
    Com_stmt_send_long_data 0
    Com_truncate    0
    Com_uninstall_plugin    0
    Com_unlock_tables   0
    Com_update  0
    Com_update_multi    0
    Com_xa_commit   0
    Com_xa_end  0
    Com_xa_prepare  0
    Com_xa_recover  0
    Com_xa_rollback 0
    Com_xa_start    0
    Compression OFF
    Connections 256
    Created_tmp_disk_tables 0
    Created_tmp_files   6
    Created_tmp_tables  0
    Delayed_errors  0
    Delayed_insert_threads  0
    Delayed_writes  0
    Flush_commands  1
    Handler_commit  0
    Handler_delete  0
    Handler_discover    0
    Handler_prepare 0
    Handler_read_first  0
    Handler_read_key    0
    Handler_read_last   0
    Handler_read_next   0
    Handler_read_prev   0
    Handler_read_rnd    0
    Handler_read_rnd_next   0
    Handler_rollback    0
    Handler_savepoint   0
    Handler_savepoint_rollback  0
    Handler_update  0
    Handler_write   0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_data   146
    Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data   2392064
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_dirty  0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_dirty  0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_flushed    0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free   8046
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_misc   0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total  8192
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_rnd   0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead   0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_ahead_evicted   0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_read_requests    490
    Innodb_buffer_pool_reads    147
    Innodb_buffer_pool_wait_free    0
    Innodb_buffer_pool_write_requests   0
    Innodb_data_fsyncs  3
    Innodb_data_pending_fsyncs  0
    Innodb_data_pending_reads   0
    Innodb_data_pending_writes  0
    Innodb_data_read    4591616
    Innodb_data_reads   157
    Innodb_data_writes  3
    Innodb_data_written 1536
    Innodb_dblwr_pages_written  0
    Innodb_dblwr_writes 0
    Innodb_have_atomic_builtins ON
    Innodb_log_waits    0
    Innodb_log_write_requests   0
    Innodb_log_writes   1
    Innodb_os_log_fsyncs    3
    Innodb_os_log_pending_fsyncs    0
    Innodb_os_log_pending_writes    0
    Innodb_os_log_written   512
    Innodb_page_size    16384
    Innodb_pages_created    0
    Innodb_pages_read   146
    Innodb_pages_written    0
    Innodb_row_lock_current_waits   0
    Innodb_row_lock_time    0
    Innodb_row_lock_time_avg    0
    Innodb_row_lock_time_max    0
    Innodb_row_lock_waits   0
    Innodb_rows_deleted 0
    Innodb_rows_inserted    0
    Innodb_rows_read    0
    Innodb_rows_updated 0
    Innodb_truncated_status_writes  0
    Key_blocks_not_flushed  0
    Key_blocks_unused   13396
    Key_blocks_used 0
    Key_read_requests   0
    Key_reads   0
    Key_write_requests  0
    Key_writes  0
    Last_query_cost 0.000000
    Max_used_connections    2
    Not_flushed_delayed_rows    0
    Open_files  51
    Open_streams    0
    Open_table_definitions  42
    Open_tables 42
    Opened_files    341
    Opened_table_definitions    0
    Opened_tables   0
    Performance_schema_cond_classes_lost    0
    Performance_schema_cond_instances_lost  0
    Performance_schema_file_classes_lost    0
    Performance_schema_file_handles_lost    0
    Performance_schema_file_instances_lost  0
    Performance_schema_locker_lost  0
    Performance_schema_mutex_classes_lost   0
    Performance_schema_mutex_instances_lost 0
    Performance_schema_rwlock_classes_lost  0
    Performance_schema_rwlock_instances_lost    0
    Performance_schema_table_handles_lost   0
    Performance_schema_table_instances_lost 0
    Performance_schema_thread_classes_lost  0
    Performance_schema_thread_instances_lost    0
    Prepared_stmt_count 0
    Qcache_free_blocks  1
    Qcache_free_memory  16759696
    Qcache_hits 0
    Qcache_inserts  0
    Qcache_lowmem_prunes    0
    Qcache_not_cached   290
    Qcache_queries_in_cache 0
    Qcache_total_blocks 1
    Queries 1200
    Questions   2
    Rpl_status  AUTH_MASTER
    Select_full_join    0
    Select_full_range_join  0
    Select_range    0
    Select_range_check  0
    Select_scan 0
    Slave_heartbeat_period  0.000
    Slave_open_temp_tables  0
    Slave_received_heartbeats   0
    Slave_retried_transactions  0
    Slave_running   OFF
    Slow_launch_threads 0
    Slow_queries    0
    Sort_merge_passes   0
    Sort_range  0
    Sort_rows   0
    Sort_scan   0
    Ssl_accept_renegotiates 0
    Ssl_accepts 0
    Ssl_callback_cache_hits 0
    Ssl_cipher  
    Ssl_cipher_list 
    Ssl_client_connects 0
    Ssl_connect_renegotiates    0
    Ssl_ctx_verify_depth    0
    Ssl_ctx_verify_mode 0
    Ssl_default_timeout 0
    Ssl_finished_accepts    0
    Ssl_finished_connects   0
    Ssl_session_cache_hits  0
    Ssl_session_cache_misses    0
    Ssl_session_cache_mode  NONE
    Ssl_session_cache_overflows 0
    Ssl_session_cache_size  0
    Ssl_session_cache_timeouts  0
    Ssl_sessions_reused 0
    Ssl_used_session_cache_entries  0
    Ssl_verify_depth    0
    Ssl_verify_mode 0
    Ssl_version 
    Table_locks_immediate   65
    Table_locks_waited  0
    Tc_log_max_pages_used   0
    Tc_log_page_size    0
    Tc_log_page_waits   0
    Threads_cached  1
    Threads_connected   1
    Threads_created 2
    Threads_running 1
    Uptime  3004
    Uptime_since_flush_status   3004
    Host    User    Password    Select_priv Insert_priv Update_priv Delete_priv Create_priv Drop_priv   Reload_priv Shutdown_priv   Process_priv    File_priv   Grant_priv  References_priv Index_priv  Alter_priv  Show_db_priv    Super_priv  Create_tmp_table_priv   Lock_tables_priv    Execute_priv    Repl_slave_priv Repl_client_priv    Create_view_priv    Show_view_priv  Create_routine_priv Alter_routine_priv  Create_user_priv    Event_priv  Trigger_priv    Create_tablespace_priv  ssl_type    ssl_cipher  x509_issuer x509_subject    max_questions   max_updates max_connections max_user_connections    plugin  authentication_string
    localhost   root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
    ubuntu  root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
    127.0.0.1   root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
    ::1 root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
    localhost   debian-sys-maint    *D9DF585749C51C0EF79A4548DF2DEBED22363D96   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       NULL
    myserver2   replicate   *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N                   0   0   0   0       NULL
    myserver1   replicate   *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N                   0   0   0   0       NULL
    Grants for replicate@myserver1
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'replicate'@'myserver1' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76'
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test1`.* TO 'replicate'@'myserver1'
    Grants for replicate@myserver2
    GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'replicate'@'myserver2' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76'
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test1`.* TO 'replicate'@'myserver2'
```

output of the slave

```
Slave_IO_State  Master_Host Master_User Master_Port Connect_Retry   Master_Log_File Read_Master_Log_Pos Relay_Log_File  Relay_Log_Pos   Relay_Master_Log_File   Slave_IO_Running    Slave_SQL_Running   Replicate_Do_DB Replicate_Ignore_DB Replicate_Do_Table  Replicate_Ignore_Table  Replicate_Wild_Do_Table Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table Last_Errno  Last_Error  Skip_Counter    Exec_Master_Log_Pos Relay_Log_Space Until_Condition Until_Log_File  Until_Log_Pos   Master_SSL_Allowed  Master_SSL_CA_File  Master_SSL_CA_Path  Master_SSL_Cert Master_SSL_Cipher   Master_SSL_Key  Seconds_Behind_Master   Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert   Last_IO_Errno   Last_IO_Error   Last_SQL_Errno  Last_SQL_Error  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids Master_Server_Id
Waiting to reconnect after a failed registration on master  192.168.56.101  replicate   3306    10  master-mysql-bin.000003 1714    mysqld-relay-bin.000007 4   master-mysql-bin.000003 Connecting  Yes                         0       0   1714    107 None        0   No                      NULL    No  1597    Master command COM_REGISTER_SLAVE failed: Access denied for user 'replicate'@'myserver2' (using password: YES) (Errno: 1045)    0           1
Host    User    Password    Select_priv Insert_priv Update_priv Delete_priv Create_priv Drop_priv   Reload_priv Shutdown_priv   Process_priv    File_priv   Grant_priv  References_priv Index_priv  Alter_priv  Show_db_priv    Super_priv  Create_tmp_table_priv   Lock_tables_priv    Execute_priv    Repl_slave_priv Repl_client_priv    Create_view_priv    Show_view_priv  Create_routine_priv Alter_routine_priv  Create_user_priv    Event_priv  Trigger_priv    Create_tablespace_priv  ssl_type    ssl_cipher  x509_issuer x509_subject    max_questions   max_updates max_connections max_user_connections    plugin  authentication_string
localhost   root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
ubuntu  root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
127.0.0.1   root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
::1 root    *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       
localhost   debian-sys-maint    *D9DF585749C51C0EF79A4548DF2DEBED22363D96   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y   Y                   0   0   0   0       NULL
myserver2   replicate   *8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N   N                   0   0   0   0       NULL
Grants for replicate@myserver2
GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'replicate'@'myserver2' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*8EC6DD34D61B5B086D17E29E3C9E2F7A3E1DDD76'
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test1`.* TO 'replicate'@'myserver2'
```

master my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 192.168.56.101
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
server-id       = 1
log_bin         = /var/log/mysql/master-mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
binlog_do_db        = test1
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

the slave my.cnf

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

# This will be passed to all mysql clients
# It has been reported that passwords should be enclosed with ticks/quotes
# escpecially if they contain "#" chars...
# Remember to edit /etc/mysql/debian.cnf when changing the socket location.
[client]
port        = 3306
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

# Here is entries for some specific programs
# The following values assume you have at least 32M ram

# This was formally known as [safe_mysqld]. Both versions are currently parsed.
[mysqld_safe]
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
nice        = 0

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
user        = mysql
pid-file    = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
socket      = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
port        = 3306
basedir     = /usr
datadir     = /var/lib/mysql
tmpdir      = /tmp
lc-messages-dir = /usr/share/mysql
skip-external-locking
#
# Instead of skip-networking the default is now to listen only on
# localhost which is more compatible and is not less secure.
bind-address        = 192.168.56.102
#
# * Fine Tuning
#
key_buffer      = 16M
max_allowed_packet  = 16M
thread_stack        = 192K
thread_cache_size       = 8
# This replaces the startup script and checks MyISAM tables if needed
# the first time they are touched
myisam-recover         = BACKUP
#max_connections        = 100
#table_cache            = 64
#thread_concurrency     = 10
#
# * Query Cache Configuration
#
query_cache_limit   = 1M
query_cache_size        = 16M
#
# * Logging and Replication
#
# Both location gets rotated by the cronjob.
# Be aware that this log type is a performance killer.
# As of 5.1 you can enable the log at runtime!
general_log_file        = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log             = 1
#
# Error log - should be very few entries.
#
log_error = /var/log/mysql/error.log
#
# Here you can see queries with especially long duration
#log_slow_queries   = /var/log/mysql/mysql-slow.log
#long_query_time = 2
#log-queries-not-using-indexes
#
# The following can be used as easy to replay backup logs or for replication.
# note: if you are setting up a replication slave, see README.Debian about
#       other settings you may need to change.
server-id       = 2
#log_bin            = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
expire_logs_days    = 10
max_binlog_size         = 100M
#binlog_do_db       = include_database_name
#binlog_ignore_db   = include_database_name
#
# * InnoDB
#
# InnoDB is enabled by default with a 10MB datafile in /var/lib/mysql/.
# Read the manual for more InnoDB related options. There are many!
#
# * Security Features
#
# Read the manual, too, if you want chroot!
# chroot = /var/lib/mysql/
#
# For generating SSL certificates I recommend the OpenSSL GUI "tinyca".
#
# ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/cacert.pem
# ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/server-cert.pem
# ssl-key=/etc/mysql/server-key.pem



[mysqldump]
quick
quote-names
max_allowed_packet  = 16M

[mysql]
#no-auto-rehash # faster start of mysql but no tab completition

[isamchk]
key_buffer      = 16M

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your grant for your replicate user is wrong, you need something like this.

```
GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'slave_user'@'myserver2' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
```

For more information:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-howto-repuser.html
```